# Entity Framework 6 cross reference table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

To all, thank you for your help in advance.

I am unable to correctly update the cross reference table using my Data-context in Entity Framework 6 that links the two entity tables .

Within my ObjectRepository, when I make the call to my datacontext to update the database, i.e. "db.SaveChanges(); , I get an INNER EXCEPTION

> "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SN_Tags' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

That error makes sense because, as it is defined now, my Datacontext is attempting to insert records into my SN_Tags table, which is a table that is already populated with Tags that I want to link to my SN_Objects.  The table that should get a record, or records inserted into it when an SN_Object is added to the database, is the SN_ObjectTags link table.  I've attempted to explain the structure below.  I hope this isn't too long.

Thank you for the help.

E_Rog

---

**SN_Objects**   An SN_Object entity can have many tags.

Columns: ObjectID, ObjectDesc, ModuleID.. etc

```
    public partial class SNObject
{
    public SNObject()
    {           

        this.SN_Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }

    public string ObjectDesc { get; set; }

    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
     ......
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> SN_Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**SN_Tags**   A Tag entity can be linked to many SN_Objects  This table is already populated with the list of tags that will be checked to see if an SN_Object should be linked to a particular Tag or Tags.

Columns: TagID, TagDesc, IsActive

```
    public partial class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        //this.SN_Objects = new List<SNObject>();
    }

    public int TagID { get; set; }

    public string TagDesc { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SNObject> SN_Objects { get; set; }
}
```

**SN_ObjectTags**  Cross reference table for the many to many relationship

Columns: ObjectID, TagID

```
As you know, no Entity exists for this Cross Reference table.
```

NOW,, here's the Mapping class files, with a few extra details referencing properties I didn't include in the Entity class files above, but the key stuff is there.

**SN_ObjectsMap**

```
    public class SN_ObjectsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SNObject>
{
    public SN_ObjectsMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ObjectID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ObjectDesc)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        this.Property(t => t.BankNameShort)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("SN_Objects");
        this.Property(t => t.ObjectID).HasColumnName("ObjectID");
        this.Property(t => t.ObjectDesc).HasColumnName("ObjectDesc");
        this.Property(t => t.ModuleID).HasColumnName("ModuleID");
        this.Property(t => t.BankNameShort).HasColumnName("BankNameShort");
        this.Property(t => t.SubModuleID).HasColumnName("SubModuleID");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.SN_Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.SN_Objects)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("SN_ObjectTags");
                m.MapLeftKey("ObjectID");
                m.MapRightKey("TagID");
            });

       this.HasRequired(t => t.TN_Banks)
            .WithMany(t => t.SN_Objects)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.BankNameShort);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.TN_Modules)
            .WithMany(t => t.SN_Objects)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ModuleID);
    }
}
```

**SN_TagsMap**

```
    public class SN_TagsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public SN_TagsMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TagID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.TagID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.TagDesc)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("SN_Tags");
        this.Property(t => t.TagID).HasColumnName("TagID");
        this.Property(t => t.TagDesc).HasColumnName("TagDesc");
        this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");


    }
}
```

**And Finally an abbreviated DataContext**

```
    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public MyContext() : base("Name=MyContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CPR> SN_ObjectCPRs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<File> SN_ObjectFiles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SNObject> SN_Objects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> SN_Tags { get; set; }

    public DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Bank> TN_Banks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Module> TN_Modules { get; set; }


    public DbSet<SubModule> TN_SubModules { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SN_ObjectCPRsMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SN_ObjectFilesMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SN_ObjectsMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SN_TagsMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new sysdiagramMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TN_BanksMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TN_ModulesMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TN_SubModulesMap());


    }
}
```

Comment: The exception you get usually means that you are inserting data into a column which has identity constraint and is being generated by DB. Haven't you checked if it is really necessary to insert the `TagID` manually? If it is so, the `IDENTITY_INSERT` has to be set to `true` on the `SN_Tags` table.

Comment: My focus here is not on the exception I am getting, but on the fact that I need to know what is wrong with my Data Context that it is adding records to SN_Tags, when what I really need is to add a record or records to the SN_ObjectTags cross reference table.  Again, I understand why the exception is happening, but I do not need to add records to SN_Tags.  Read the final paragraph above.